# Finding a compact set containing the unit ball in a normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I would like to show that there is a compact set $K \supset \{ \Vert x \Vert \leq 1 \}$ in a general normed vector-space $X$, but I have no clue how to do it.
Or is it maybe possible to have a finite cover of compact sets of $\{ \Vert x \Vert \leq 1 \}$?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

As in any infinite-dimensional normed space the unit ball $B_X := \{x : \|x\| \le 1\}$ is **not** compact, there will be neither a compact set containing $B_X$ (as this would imply $B_X$'s compactness as a closed subset of a compact set) nor a finite cover by compacts (as a finite union of compacts is compact).